# referencing a variable filename

Tags: python, variables, filenames, blender

Hi i am trying to write a python script in blender that involves the following command:

```
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath = r"C:\Users\mrryan\Desktop\ 'customer_id' + orangecube.blend)
```

The idea is that the script saves the file using both a variable and a standard file name'
for example;

To create `3141orangecube.blend`

I have defined `customer_id` as:

```
customer_id = "3141"
```

Without this variable my script works fine, but  suspect an error in the syntax.

Please help.

Comment: You probably wanted to write: `r"C:\Users\mrryan\Desktop\" + 'customer_id' + "orangecube.blend"`.

Comment: Thanks , buti tried this and it generates a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
filepath = os.path.join(r"C:\Users\mrryan\Desktop", customer_id + "orangecube.blend")
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath = filepath)
```

Don't forget to `import os` at the top of the file.

Comment: Tried this and it generates an invalid syntax error. If it helps i included `import bpy, and import ops, at the start of the file

Comment: @RyanHamilton see my edit. I can't speak for the rest of your file, but the syntax error was probably from the "\" at the end of your string. On Windows, using `os.path.join()` is a much less error-prone way of constructing filenames.

Answer (score 0):

[This is how we concatenate strings:](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

```
foo = '42'
print 'bar' + foo + 'baz'
```

Comment: How can this be applied to a file name?

Comment: A filename is a string.